# Correct SQL statement needed in my scenario

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

I'm having a problem in having my desired result in my database. I want to extract Total Row Count from other table where in it's condition will be belong to the other table. To make it clear, Here is the sample illustration.

```
>tblBus
>
>Bus ID ~ Day~ Type 
>
>1000 | Monday |  Public

>2000|Monday | Private

>3000|Tuesday| Public

>4000|Monday | Public


>tblReservation 
>
>Bus ID | Date

>1000   | 2013/3/4

>2000   | 2013/3/4

>3000   | 2013/3/6
```

Let say that the reservation day would be on Monday and that is 2013/3/4.. I want to display all PUBLIC buses that is available on Monday with a new row that has the total number of reservation made on that bus.

e.g.

GeneratedTable (WHERE Date ='2013/3/4', Type='Public', Day='Monday')

```
>Bus ID | Day | Type | TotalNumberReservation

>1000   |Monday | Public | 1

>4000   |Monday | Public | 1
```

Comment: `JOIN`, `GROUP BY` & `COUNT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following which joins your tables on the `bus id` and then gets a count of the reservations:

```
select b.`bus id`,
  b.day,
  b.type,
  count(r.date) TotalNumberReservation
from tblBus b
inner join tblReservation r
  on b.`bus id` = r.`bus id`
where r.date = '2013-03-04'
  and b.day = 'Monday'
group by b.`bus id`, b.day, b.type
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91238/8)

If you want to return all rows that match the correct day even if there is not a reservation, then you will want to use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select b.`bus id`,
  b.day,
  b.type,
  count(r.date) TotalNumberReservation
from tblBus b
left join tblReservation r
  on b.`bus id` = r.`bus id`
  AND r.date = '2013-03-04'
where b.day = 'Monday'
group by b.`bus id`, b.day, b.type
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91238/7)

Comment: Edited: It has a problem it should still display all bus that has the same day. e.g. all bus in monday

Comment: @DandeloDarkyCardona see my edit, you will need to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead

Comment: I already tried it on my system and It worked flawlessly! Thank You! :D Till next time ^_^ you're such a pro!

Comment: @DandeloDarkyCardona You are welcome!  Always happy to help a fellow user.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic query to generate the counts for all busses, days, and dates that you can then filter as you need:

```
Select a.bus_id, day, type, count(*) as TotalNumberReservation
  from tblBus a
  join tblReservation b
    on a.busId=b.busId
 group by a.bus_id,day,type
```